# How to read web.config's value in ascx page

Tags: c#-4.0, web-config

I want to access the web.config's value in ascx page(design page) and have to assign these values to a drop down list.how to do that?any help

Comment: what values from web.config? please elaborate

Comment: example : <add key="test" value="test2,test3"/> these test2,test3 values i want to display in drop down list

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ASP.NET Configuration API Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228060.aspx)

See the **Code Examples** on that page

Comment: I need it for drop down list control and i must read from web.config and display the values in the drop down list

Answer (score 1):

If you're set on doing it that way, it is probably best to create a custom section in your web.config to hold these values (and then create a class to pull them into a collection you can query in the .ascx). Here is a good [walk-through](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133931/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/032807-1.aspx).

Just as an example though, if at the top of your .ascx page you include a directive:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Configuration" %>
```

You can pull in an app setting by embedding:

```
<select>
   <option value="<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Foo"]%>">Foo</option>
   <option value="<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Bar"]%>">Bar</option>
</select>
```

Like I said, I would use a more strongly typed way to access the data, but the above is just in the way of an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
var settings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
foreach (var setting in settings)
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(settings[setting.ToString()]);
}
```